# How to split a multiline string with space-delimited integers to a list of lists for each line

Tags: python, string, list

Is there a simple way to divide a multiline string into different lists with different sizes? 
I have this elements in a file:

```
5 5 6 7 8 9
1 3 4 53 4
1 23
13 312
22 111 123
```

I would like to get an array/list with these elements

`list= [5,5,6,7,8,9],[1,3,4,53,4],[1,23],[13,312],[22,111,123]`

It must be applied to any file (they will always be files with integers), the important thing is that it divides the array/ list in each '\n'

I want to avoid using external import (like NumPy for example), I just have to do it with the tools that Python offers.

Comment: What are you getting now? This can be done in ~4 lines of code.

Comment: Obligatory comment that reminds you that `list` is not a good variable name because then you can't use the built in `list` callable any longer. :)

Comment: "I have been stuck in this problem for days" We like it when somebody tries something before asking here, so that's good. Your question will probably gather some upvotes if you include your attempts in the question and explain how they failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty easy. Remember that files are iterables over lines.

```
>>> # demo-list that imitates your file
>>> file = '''5 5 6 7 8 9
... 1 3 4 53 4
... 1 23
... 13 312
... 22 111 123'''.splitlines()
>>> 
>>> [map(int, line.split()) for line in file]
[[5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 3, 4, 53, 4], [1, 23], [13, 312], [22, 111, 123]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code which read all lines of a text file to a list, then make a list from each line:

```
with open('path/to/your/file', 'r') as f:
    lists = [line.strip().split() for line in f]
```

Comment: The `readlines` is unnecesary, you can iterate over `f` directly.

Comment: @timgeb Thank you. Edited accordingly + added `strip()` to delete newline characters.